# Ford Focus MK3 disable key free entry

Tags: ford, security, keyless-entry

I'm driving a German ford focus MK3 titanium with key free entry. But I read a article about a security issue with this function.

Can someone explain me how to disable it without losing Keyfree start function? It's not shown in the manual for this vehicle.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a link of the article? Is there a number code panel near the door handle? Is it a third generation Ford Focus? Is it a push button start option that works with a key fob? What year is the vehicle?

Comment: Yes I have a link but it is German. http://m.heise.de/security/meldung/ADAC-Viele-aktuelle-Pkw-Modelle-ueber-Funk-knackbar-3140796.html   yes it is with button start. Mk3 means third generation.

Comment: Google Chrome can probably translate it.

Comment: Do you want to physically disable the system? Would you like to cut off the signal that the key puts out when the vehicle is not in use?

Comment: I know there is more than one sensor around the car for the keyless entry, you would have to disable all of them. Not sure if and how they could be tied to the power starter

Comment: Cross-site related question, which actually provides you with some possible answers: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117696/how-to-patch-keyless-entry-car-keys

Comment: Yes it is nearly the same thing but I search for a software configuration to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the key-less entry system operates via wireless signals without physical contact to the ignition system.... You may be able to use tinfoil to cover the key so that the signal that the key puts out may not be boosted.

The key-less systems seem very similar to RFID cards if not the same. I think that they have RFID technology in Europe for awhile now. They make wallets that have a tinfoil lining that block RFID signals.

Amazon has Key-fob protectors and this website sells them as well. 
http://www.fobguard.com/

You can also make your own key-fob signal protector. This article below is more suitable for storage in a house or apartment setting or something else.

The fob-guards are more mobile.

http://makezine.com/2015/08/14/block-car-door-relay-hack-faraday-cage/

With this setup you may not have to disable the key-less entry system. You would have to take the key out of the key-fob guard when you want to use the key-less entry feature.

I suggest consulting with a Ford dealer if this setup shall work or if they have any recommendations.

There is talk of a electronic chip that is in the works that will tell how far the key is really from the vehicle to counter the signal boosters. The chip would signal that the key is really this far and would not listen to the signal booster. I think the chip functions like a radar or a Lojack system to tell the distance.

Comment: Yes it is right but I would like to use keyless start. Because no physical key is available.

Comment: The key-fob guard that I mentioned in the answer above is a case that should block the signals. Most key-fobs have square keys with a push-button that flicks a key out of the key-fob. I know Chevrolet vehicles have done this for awhile now. I think it is like a laser cut key. Can you send a picture of the key-less entry near the steering wheel or in the car cabin? Can send a picture of what the key-fob looks like?

Comment: No key hohl near the stirring wheel and no metal key only a remote

Comment: I don't know why the engineers would design it like that. If the key-fob doesn't work or it gets short-circuited you may most likely be stranded. - Unless you have a spare or get a spare key-fob that can be synchronized with the car. If you get a key-fob guard that should protect the key-fob from signal boost theft attacks.

Comment: The key looks like this one the bottom of the site http://www.asf-autoservice.de/ford-technologie/ford-key-free-system/

Comment: I suggest getting a Key-fob guard case to protect the key from signal-boosting theft attacks. This should prevent your car from getting stolen via a key-fob signal booster. Please see my answer above and the websites I provided.

Comment: I'm really thankful for the idea to use a key fob. But I hope someone knows the software and can tell us how to disable it probably. It's a question about comfort.

Comment: As far as I know it's mostly electrical engineering. The software would be like if key-fob is this close open car. If car key is not close to car do not open car. I think this is more of an electronic hardware problem. They soon be able to encrypt the signal ,but that is an entire other discussion which would probably be in another forum. There must be a pro and cons list somewhere for key-less entry. If people made it they can break it or "hack" it and destroy it - most of the time.

Comment: But there are so many hidden menus and tricks in modern cars. I can't believe that you can not disable the keyless entry

Comment: If you want to discuss this more we can go into a stack exchange chat room another time.